# Spring Boot & AngularJS / global exception handler

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, exception

I'm very new in AngularJS and want implement global exception handler on REST application by best practice.

Spring global exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    public void defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Throwable exp) {
        // redirect and bind exception to error.html
    }
}
```

For example on Angular controller I invoke `$http.get` request on Spring controller that thrown `NPE`.

How to bind catched exception object to `error.html`?

Comment: You want to send a view response as error.html?

Comment: @LaurentiuL. No. I want redirect to error.html using Angular

Comment: Ideally you should not return such thing from global exception handler. You should sent appropriate response(JSON or XML) in the case of exception. It would help you when your APIs would be used by other people such as Mobile App development.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this, we will have to add a service/factory to intercept http calls. You can do it like this in your config

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
```

Now, the above service will be something like this

```
angular.module("app").factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function ($q) {

            return {
                'request': function (config) {

                    // Extract request information
                    return config || $q.when(config);
                },
                'responseError': function(rejection) {

                    // Extract response error information and handle errors
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                 }
             }
        });
```

In response error information block, you can redirect to the error.html page.

Comment: @Anton Dozortsev - I am going to bed now. Do share me your findings/updates. Also, if you find my answer correct, mark it as selected. Good night. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following approach worked for me.

```
myApp.factory('responseObserver',
  function responseObserver($q, $window, $rootScope) {
    return function (promise) {
        return promise.then(function (successResponse) {
            return successResponse;
        }, function (errorResponse) {

        switch (errorResponse.status) {
        //server error
        case 500:
            $rootScope.redirectToErrorPage();
            break;
        //If unauthorized
        case 401:
            $rootScope.logout();
            break;      
       }
       return $q.reject(errorResponse);
      });
    };
});

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('responseObserver');

    $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html', 
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .state('error', {
        url: '/error',
        templateUrl: 'templates/error.html'
    })

});

myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.redirectToErrorPage = function()
    {
        $state.transitionTo("error");
    }
    $rootScope.logout = function()
    {
        $state.transitionTo("login");
    }

}]);
```